How to safely access vector references in C++14
I have a class managing vector data using the singleton pattern.
class DataManager
{
public:
    static DataManager& GetInstance() {
        static DataManager instance;
        return instance;
    }
    const vector<int>& GetData() const{return data;}
    void SetData(vector<int>& data_)
    {
        data.swap(data_);
    }
private:
    vector<int> data;
};

I need to access this data and modify it within a thread. However, if the data is released while accessing it, the program will throw an error.
I made the following attempts:
Pass the lock as a parameter:
class DataManager
{
prublic:
    const std::vector<int>& GetRects(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lock) const
    {
        lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m_mutex_data);
        return data;
    }
...
private:
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex_data;
}

This can work, but it's strange. Is there a better way?

You are returning data but also lock (via modification) which I think is a bad interface. Who will unlock the lock? Will data go out of scope first or the lock be released first? It's incredibly easy to mess this up. It would be better to define a proxy class that holds both the lock and data reference that will unlock in the destructor. You also have to be careful with the vector getting resized or moved in one thread while another accesses the data. For now I assume you handle that in the ... part of the example code.

I don't understand the issue. GetRects returns a const reference. You cannot modify the vector nor its elements via the result of this function. SetData is the thing that should be synchronised between threads.

@Yksisarvinen "You cannot modify the vector nor its elements via the result of this function" yeah but somebody else can.

@Yksisarvinen Both need to synchronize. Calling SetData while a thread accesses the data returned by GetRects would be fatal.  I assumed that is handled in the ....

make a copy. Any access to a reference (const or not) must be synchronized with other threads. If you want a thread to get the value and work on it independelty make a copy

Ah, right, I see it now.

Instead of GetRects you can have a public method that applies some transformation over the data under the lock (the transformation can be given e.g. using a lambda or std::function).

Expanding on what @wohlstad wrote: I would not have a method that returns the vector at all. Why not have an operator() or at method and an apply method for larger transformations. You can even allow chaining of operations so a single lock is used for multiple operations.

Returning a lock and relying on the user of the class to unlock is very shaky.
You mentioned that you need to modify the data in a thread-safe way.
For this you can add a public method to DataManager that will accept a callable that will modify the data, and invoke it under the lock.
Something like (just a sketch):
class DataManager
{
public:
   template <typename T>
   void TransformDataUnderLock(T && transformer)
   {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex_data);
       transformer(data);
   }

   // ...

private:
   std::vector<int> data;
   mutable std::mutex m_mutex_data;
};

Notes:

You should also apply similar scope locking in your SetData method (or any other method that accesses data).

This patern might not protect against a mallicious user, but it will protect against accidental wrong usage of the accessed data and the lock (which can be much more common).

This pattern might cause a deadlock due to the fact that the lock is held during invocation of the transformer code which you have no control over. But as long as it is a simple transformation of the data you should be fine.



if someone wants to break it, they can still use transformer to get their hands on a not-locked reference, though it is unlikely to happen by accident

std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m_mutex_data); is a temporary that lives only until end of the line, no?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai regarding your first comment - sure, but avoiding accidental "damages" (which are much more common than malicious ones) was the main purpose of my idea.

std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m_mutex_data); doesnt compile https://godbolt.org/z/8eToGE3cc ;)

"avoiding accidental "damages" (which are much more common than malicious ones) was the main purpose of my idea" and thats good. It was no critizism, I just thought it is worth mentioning.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai you missed the lock_guard variable name (lock) - with it it compiles - see here. I think your comment about a temporary that lives till the end of the line is also related to not having a variable name.

At first glance this looks good, but there is potential risk of deadlock. Basically you should not hold a lock when invoking arbitrary code (code which content is unknown and you can't reason that it will not hold other locks). So since you can't tell what transformer can do and if he acquire other locks, this code introduces risk that you will have a deadlock in a future.

@MarekR I agree. Do you have a better idea ? it seemed to me that either the DataManager should manage locking, or the user, and relying on the user is even more fragile.  Anyway added a note about it.
